# I can't make a new Unity Project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an error with creating a project with unity Hub (Editor 2021.2.9)

Here is the error message:

Could not find Unity Package Manager local server application at [/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.2.9f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/Server/UnityPackageManager]. Missing files could be the result of an antivirus action or a corrupt Unity installation.

I tried to look it up but I don't have a Unity.app folder.

How do I get it? I tried to reinstall it and still there is nothing there.

I'm on a MacBook M1.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please tell me how I can improve my question or what informations to add instead of downvoting, thank you.

Comment: I can’t get at a mac to look but turn off any antivirus and reinstall unity. Not unity hub. The unity version

Comment: I deleted everything 2 times and reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to turn off antivirus and reinstall it again